# How to add external .less file into bootstrap 3.3.6?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, color-scheme

I want to add .less file into my bootstrap project but I am totally new to .less so please anyone can help to add .less file into my project.

I'm trying to add .less file for color scheme here is the link 
http://rriepe.github.io/1pxdeep

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new stylesheet, i.e. `style.less`, and reference `bootstrap.less`, as well as your custom Less files.

For example,

```
// style.less

@import "bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap"; // path to bootstrap.less
@import "my-component";
```